# Can't buy house in riften

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

**What I did**

- The skooma questline.
- 5 Misc quest from riften citizens.
- Collected the 8000 Gold.

After that, the Jarl told me that I can buy a house from the steward.
If I talk to the steward I have the option to buy the house but if I click it, the only option I have is saying "I'd rather wait some time and think about this decision again". I already tried waiting a long time. But that didn't help.
I'm level 13, if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known glitch. Here's the only info about a bug related on the [wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Honeyside):

> There's a possibility of becoming unable to buy the house, Even after doing "The Raid" and "Supply and Demand" quest. The cause to this bug is currently unknown. However, helping more people around Riften seems to help.

One solution is to help more people in Riften, like giving donations to beggers, giving a healing potion to an argonian worker, helping Brand Shei for evidence about him, giving materials to Madesi, bringing Fire Salts to the blacksmith.

Comment: That bug report also says this: "Workaround: Use the console command setstage FreeformRiftenThane 10."